# angular save() method not working hero tutorial

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework

Following the Angular (using 7.3.4) Hero Tutorial. Using angular with a django backend. I cannot seem to get a hero name to update:

I have a **hero-detail.component.ts** that has a `save()` method which should update the `hero` via the `HeroService.updateHero()` method. When i click the save button nothing happens at all...

I am suspicious that the `heroService.updateHero` method is pointing to the wrong url, but I am not sure where to point it or what to pass it to. Also using Pycharm and `put` in `return this.http.put(this.heroesUrl, hero, httpOptions` is red as an unresolved function, but i think this is just a Typescript Pycharm setting that should not matter.

Any pointers appreciated.

**hero-detail.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from '../hero'
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { HeroService }  from '../hero.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero-detail',
  templateUrl: './hero-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hero-detail.component.scss']
})
export class HeroDetailComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private heroService: HeroService,
  private location: Location
) {}

  @Input() hero: Hero;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getHero();
  }

  getHero(): void {
    const number = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('number');
    this.heroService.getHero(number)
      .subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero);
  }

  save(): void {
   this.heroService.updateHero(this.hero)
     .subscribe(() => this.goBack());
 }

  goBack(): void {
  this.location.back();
}
```

**hero.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HEROES } from './mock-heroes';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs'
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http'
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
  };

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class HeroService {

private heroesUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/heroes/';  // URL to web api

  constructor(
  private http : HttpClient
) { }


  getHeroes (): Observable<Hero[]> {
  return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl)

}

  getHero(id:number): Observable<Hero>{
    return this.http.get<Hero>(`${this.heroesUrl}${id}`);
  }

  updateHero (hero: Hero): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put(this.heroesUrl, hero, httpOptions)
  }

}


  }
```

**heroes/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.response import Response

from .models import Hero
from rest_framework import generics
from .serializers import HeroSerializer
# Create your views here.


class HeroList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Hero.objects.all()
    serializer_class = HeroSerializer

    class Meta:
        model = Hero
        fields = ('number', 'name','id')


class HeroDetail(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = HeroSerializer

    def get(self, request, id):
        hero_detail = Hero.objects.get(id=id)
        serializer = HeroSerializer(hero_detail)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def put(self, request, id):
        hero_detail = Hero.objects.get(id=id)
        # hero_detail.name = request.data.get("name")
        hero_detail.save()
        serializer = HeroSerializer(hero_detail)
        return Response(serializer.data)



    class Meta:
        model = Hero
        fields = ('number', 'name','id')
```

**hero-detail.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="hero">

<h2>{{hero.name | uppercase}} Details</h2>
<div><span>id: </span>{{hero.id}}</div>
<div>
  <label>name:
    <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name">
  </label>
</div>

</div>

<button (click)="goBack()">go back</button>
<button (click)="save()">save</button>
```

Comment: What return are you getting from your put request?

Comment: Can not be sure without seeing your django urls file, but probably you should send the put request to `${this.heroesUrl}${hero.id}/`,

Comment: @OzgurAkcali i actually tried that but the `updateHero()` method only gets passed a hero and not a hero id, so I tried `${this.heroesUrl}${hero.id}` instead and this seems to work, if you post an answer i can mark correct, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should send the put request to '/heroes/hero_id/' for updates. With the restful APIs, in general, you should send

- POST request to /heroes/ -> Create hero
- GET request to /heroes/ -> List heroes
- GET request to /heroes/id/ -> Retrieve single hero
- PUT request to /heroes/id/ -> Update hero
- DELETE request to /heroes/id/ -> Delete hero

So in your example, you should modify your updateHero method like this:

```
updateHero (hero: Hero): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put(`${this.heroesUrl}${hero.id}/` hero, httpOptions)
}
```